# How does one debug sqlite3_prepare_v2 and sqlite3_step not giving expected values when no error codes are generated?

Tags: c++, sqlite, unreal-engine4

I am having problems using the sqlite3 C/C++ amalgamation within the context of Unreal Engine 4...

I can open a connection to the database write data to it, verifying this using DB Browser, but running `SELECT` statements using `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` is giving unexpected behaviours. I'm checking the return values and not seeing any error codes, but I am seeing a `SQLITE_DONE` when I'd expect to see `SQLITE_ROW` returned by `sqlite3_step`. If I log out the result of `sqlite3_expanded_sql`, I get the expected statement with all parameters properly inserted and if I copy & paste this into DB Browser, I get the expected results.

The data being pulled is specific to each run of the program so I know that I'm not seeing old or irrelevant data in DB Browser, and I know that my "write" functions are also operating as expected.

What's particularly strange is that after *commenting out* all references to `SQLPreparedStatementString` (which I was using in an attempt to debug the issue) the code performs differently: I do now get one row back (instead of the expected 4).

This almost makes me suspect that there's a memory issue going on, perhaps sqlite3 and Unreal are both writing to the same sections of memory without communicating that to each other? I tend to rely on UE4's memory management and don't have a lot of C/C++ experience outside of UE4, so my knowledge of things like `malloc` is limited pretty much just to the general feeling that "here be dragons" etc. I also understand that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` are functions that tend to do a lot of memory allocation, but if that's what's causing the problem, I'm surprised that it's only occuring so rarely, since I'm successfully calling them several thousand times (to add data) on each game run.

I understand that it's possible to set compile-time options for sqlite that pre-allocate it a memory block so that it doesn't use malloc at all during runtime, but I've not quite worked out how to do that in the context of including the amalgamation in UE4 just yet.

Relevant code below:

```cpp
TArray<FName> UOzyBrainLogger::GetLoggedCivsForTurn(const int32 TurnNumber)
{
    TArray<FName> rVal;
    
        sqlite3_stmt *SQLStatement;
        FString SQLCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT CivName FROM Decision WHERE (GameID = ? AND TurnNumber = ?) ;";
        int rc;
        
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*SQLCommand), -1, &SQLStatement, NULL);
        if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //FString SQLPreparedStatementString;
            UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Log, TEXT("Getting Civs logged for turn %d in game %s"), TurnNumber, *GameID);
            if(sqlite3_bind_text(  SQLStatement, 1, TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*GameID), -1, SQLITE_STATIC) == SQLITE_OK &&
               sqlite3_bind_int(   SQLStatement, 2, TurnNumber)                                == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //SQLPreparedStatementString = UTF8_TO_TCHAR(sqlite3_expanded_sql(SQLStatement));
                //UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Log, TEXT("Successfully created statement: %s"), *SQLPreparedStatementString);
                rc = sqlite3_step(SQLStatement);
                if (rc == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Log, TEXT("No results found?"));
                }
                else if (rc != SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Log, TEXT("Return code was: %d"), rc);
                }
                while (rc == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    FName CivName = FName(*FString(UTF8_TO_TCHAR((const char*) sqlite3_column_text(SQLStatement, 0))));
                    //UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Log, TEXT("Returning %s for turn %d via statement: %s"), *CivName.ToString(), TurnNumber, *SQLPreparedStatementString);
                    UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Log, TEXT("Returning %s for turn %d"), *CivName.ToString(), TurnNumber);
                    
                    rVal.Add(CivName);
                    rc = sqlite3_step(SQLStatement);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Warning, TEXT("%s"), UTF8_TO_TCHAR(sqlite3_errmsg(DB)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UE_LOG(OzyBrainLogger, Warning, TEXT("%s"), UTF8_TO_TCHAR(sqlite3_errmsg(DB)));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(SQLStatement);
    
    return rVal;
}
```

I might be missing something really obvious, but I'm not sure how to investigate this further to make progress so any advice on avenues to explore would be very helpful.

Am feeling a bit lost!

Comment: I suggest two things: (1) rewrite the code to "push to the left": instead of if/then/else, more like: if error then return. This tends to make the code easier to understand and reason about. (2) check and react to all error codes, for example sometimes the code logs and keeps going although there has been an error. Another example is the call to sqlite3_finalize(), missing error checking.

Comment: Ah, good point about error checking on `sqlite3_finalize`. Doesn't seem to be catching anything though. I'd initially avoided the "if fail then return" pattern to reduce the chance of creating a return branch that didn't clean up after itself. Have "shifted left" as you describe though, am always open to hear views on best practices etc.

Comment: I'm having a go at using `sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP, SQLiteDBMemoryHeap, 2^25, 64);` where `SQLiteDBMemoryHeap` is allocated via `FMemory::Malloc(2^25, 8);` but I then get a `SQLITE_NOMEM` return code when I try to open the database. The DB is currently only around 57kb on disk, so I'm surprised that it's saying it doesn't have enough memory. Is there something blocking sqlite from being able to use memory allocated by an UE4 function? I thought that at least if I used FMemory, it would ensure then at least one would know about the other...

Comment: `2^25` is 27 bytes... That's far, far too small a memory buffer to use.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework you're using, but using `SQLITE_STATIC` with `TCHAR_TO_UTF8()` smells funny.

Comment: *These macros use a class instance declared in local scope and allocate space on the stack, so it is very important you do not retain pointers to them!* Yeah... Given that note in the documentation, your usage is definitely problematic.

Comment: Try using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` instead so it makes a copy of the string.

Comment: I remember reading that in the docs and being a little uncomfortable with that as I'm also not super familiar with what the `TCHAR_TO_UTF8` macros do. So I've tried using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` instead but doing that actually leads to a hard crash on `sqlite3_close`, whether using `SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP` or not. (Also, thanks for pointing out the rookie error in `2^25`! I've only been using C++ for about 6 months so am still definitely learning even some of the simpler syntax and conventions etc.)

Comment: Ok, I found that calling `sqlite3_open` in my object's constructor was causing a few issues, since the UE4 Editor automatically calls constructors of objects after compiling (not just when the game runs) so have pulled that into a separate `Initialise` method which is only ever called when the game runs. Now I can safely use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` without it crashing on `sqlite3_close` and adding/removing debug lines no longer seems to change the results I get back from the query. However, I'm still now only getting 2 results back, rather than all 4 as expected. Better at least I guess!?

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to fix it! The problem seems to have been a combination of:

1. Calling `sqlite3_open` in my object's constructor expecting singleton-like behaviour when UE4 calls constructors silently from time to time (e.g. on compile).
2. Using `SQLITE_STATIC` in place of `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`
3. Adding return code (`rc`) checking absolutely *everywhere*

Fixing both of these issues seems to have resolved the main problem.

The final issue (getting only 2 rows back instead of 4) was a more pedestrian rookie error (I'd rearranged the call to `sqlite3_step` into a `do ... while` loop and accidentally ended up calling `sqlite3_step` twice per iteration!

The things that didn't fix the main issue included calling `sqlite3_config` with `SQLITE_CONFIG_MEMSTATUS`, `SQLITE_CONFIG_LOOKASIDE` and `SQLITE_CONFIG_HEAP`, *however*: when I started checking the return codes for these calls properly and finding errors, that was a major clue to realising that *something had already started the database connection* without me realising it (i.e. UE4's silent constructor-calling on compile)

Comment: Kudos for having persevered and for having taken the time to report here what was wrong.

Comment: If you want one thing to remember from this experience: ALWAYS check error codes. It could look boring or cluttering on the surface, but it saves your bacon down the road.